# Destroy action on nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Im trying to add a destroy button on my nested resource and getting this error: `No route matches [DELETE] "/users/1/2/4/5/holidays/7"`

Heres the relevant parts of my view,routes, models, & controllers:

```
<% @user.holidays.each do |h| %>
  <td><%= h.name %></td>
  <td><%= h.date %></td>
  <td>
    <%= button_to('Destroy', user_holiday_path(@user.holidays), :method => 'delete', :class => 'btn btn-large btn-primary')  %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Routes

```
resources :users do
  resources :interests
  resources :holidays
end
```

Models

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :holidays, :through => :user_holidays
end

class UserHoliday < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :holiday_id, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :holiday
end

class Holiday < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :date
  has_many :user_holidays
  has_many :users, :through => :user_holidays

end
```

Controller

```
class HolidaysController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user_holidays = Holiday.find(params[:user_id])
    @holidays = @user_holidays.holidays
  end

  def new
  end

  def show
    @holiday = Holiday.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @holiday }
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @holiday = Holiday.find(params[:id])
    @holiday.destroy
  end
end
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: @rb512 has the right answer below, but I wanted to point out that you should be using more descriptive names for variables. You are using `h` in your views, but this should be something more like `holiday`. Besides gaining clarity, `h` is also an [alias for html_escape](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-h) so it removes some confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this : 
`<%= button_to('Destroy', user_holiday_path(@user.holidays), :method => 'delete', :class => 'btn btn-large btn-primary')  %>`
to this: 
`<%= button_to('Destroy', user_holiday_path(h), :method => 'delete', :class => 'btn btn-large btn-primary')  %>`

**Update**

Change your destroy action from :
`@holiday = Holiday.find(params[:id])` to 
`@user_holiday = UserHoliday.find(params[:id])`

and in your view:
change 
`<% @user.holidays.each do |h| %>`
 to

`<% @user.user_holidays.each do |h| %>`

Your associations need some correction and should be as follows:
`user has_many user_holidays` 
`user_holiday has_one holiday`
`user_holidays belongs_to user`

You can access name and holiday via your h object: 
`h.holiday.name`
`h.holiday.date`

Comment: thanks! only problem is this is deleting the pre-populated data from my "holidays" table not the actual records that are related to the user in the "user_holidays" table..

Comment: how should i change my destroy action?

Comment: Now this error: "undefined method `holidays' for nil:NilClass" .. also, the user id is not correct in the paramaters that show in this error so could it be something with that?

Comment: In other words, my view shows a list of all of the holidays that a single user has.. the destroy button that is rendered next to each holiday has a different user_id paramater when submited, which should not be the case

Comment: my bad, i should 've explicitly mentioned this.  the problem here is, your destroy action doesn't know what is @user, because it's not initialized, i.e. it's nil. Evaluating nil.holidays.find(params[:id]) would not be possible, hence the error message.

As for the params, the id you see next to the destroy button is not user_id but holiday_id. When you click on the delete button (that deletes a user holiday), id of that holiday will be passed to the controller.

Comment: you don't really need any association between user-holiday and holiday-user_holiday.  the only association required is user has_many user_holidays.

Comment: thanks again.. the only problem with changing to <% @user.user_holidays.each do |h| %> is the the name and date (see entire view at top) are stored within the holidays table not the user_holidays table.. user holidays is the join..

Comment: alright, am confused. what do you want to delete? holiday or user_holiday?

Comment: ok sorry i probably was not clear.. table "holidays" is solely used to populate a list of checkboxes with holidays (including their names and dates)..This table should never be altered.. user_holidays (join table) stores which users celebrate the holidays.. this is the record i am attempting to give the user the option to delete.. their own association with the holiday (stored in holiday_user)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11620/discussion-between-rb512-and-nkeating)